# How to integrate Serial Port Communication in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, serial-port

I am very new to iOS development. I want to communicate with RN52 chip over Bluetooth through my iOS app using Serial Port Communication. Can any one tell me how to implement this? Or is their any tutorial which will help me?

Do I need  MFi certificate for this?

Comment: Yes, you will need MFi license for using SPP (see section 2.3 of the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/rn-52-ds-1.0r.pdf)). I think you should be able to use audio features without MFi - but don't take my word for it. If you only need SPP without audio you might want to consider RN41-APL (MFi needed) or one of the BLE modules (no MFi needed)

Comment: @rokjarc thank you for your reply.I have RN52 chip and i want to communicate with that chip. Yes, I am playing audio on that bluetooth device over bluetooth from my iOS app. Do you have any tutorial which will help me??? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually all i have on RN52 are datasheets that are freely downloadable from the web. Documentation on RN41-APL is under pretty strict NDA (it has a watermark signature so i really can't share that).