# Is SPP is open in iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, serial-port

I want to communicate with RN52 chip over bluetooth using SPP. I found that SPP is not open in iOS SDK. If i do registration to MFi program, then can i access bluetooth devices over bluetooth using SPP in iOS SDK?.

Comment: How this question is differ from your this question:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737793/how-to-integrate-serial-port-communication-in-ios-sdk. Please expalin.

Comment: @PiyushDubey I m planning to do registration to MFi program. But i found that Apple device does not support SPP, we have to go for iAP. But our hardware team is developing bluetooth device which supports SPP. 
I just wanted to know that, can i access that RN52 chip after registration to MFi program?. Or after registration also apple devices does not support the SPP profile for communication with RN52 chip.

Comment: My question is how your above question is differ from your previous question?

Comment: @PiyushDubey do u have any idea. I am totally confused, wether iPhone supports SPP profile after MFi program registration.